# insert span or li tag while echo ing the content

Tags: php, html, echo

I need to insert span tag after every line break in my content while echoing.

How can i achieve this?

I know that `nl2br(string)`it inserts the XHTML compliant.

```
 The nl2br() function inserts HTML line breaks (<br />) in front of
   each newline (\n) in a string.
```

- how to get `<span>` tag in my content using echo or while displaying my
  content after every line break in the content...
- I also need to insert `<li>` tag in my cotent while displaying the data
  using echo

any idea. 
Its simple requirement but i'm not getting
   any idea how to solve this?

Any help much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: many my qns are un answered laxonline..how can i accept them?? if no one answers it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why echoing `"<span>"` wouldn't work for you, but you can always write html in php code. For example:

```
foreach($result in $results)
{
?>
    <a>
<?php
    echo $result["column"];
?>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: thans for your reply friend.. but i got huge content in one variable..so i cant do foreach here..it just content with 10 paragraph's coming from back end. so i cant style it while displaying it. so i need to insert span tag or li tag while echoing out....

Answer (score 1):

i found this one..i'm looking something like this for span as predfined function is not available for echo...

```
    function nl2p($string, $line_breaks = true, $xml = true)
{
    // Remove existing HTML formatting to avoid double-wrapping things
    $string = str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>', '<br>', '<br />'), '', $string);

    // It is conceivable that people might still want single line-breaks
    // without breaking into a new paragraph.
    if ($line_breaks == true)
        return '<p>'.preg_replace(array("/([\n]{2,})/i", "/([^>])\n([^<])/i"), array("</p>\n<p>", '<br'.($xml == true ? ' /' : '').'>'), trim($string)).'</p>';
    else 
        return '<p>'.preg_replace("/([\n]{1,})/i", "</p>\n<p>", trim($string)).'</p>';
}  


    <?php
$text = "Hello.

My name is Geoffrey.";

echo nl2p($text);
?>
```

thanks all :)